# Switching hard drives

Tags: hard-drive, windows-7, hardware

I have Windows 7 installed on a 640 GB hard drive, and Ubuntu on a 2TB. I have leaned towards storing all music, pictures, movies, etc. on Windows, and have low storage space. I was wondering if it was at all possible to swap the disks (putting Windows on the 2TB, and Ubuntu on the 640GB) without using a 3rd hard drive for transfer.

Edit: Output of `df -h`

```
udev            3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           785M  9.5M  775M   2% /run
/dev/sdc2        47G  7.8G   37G  18% /
tmpfs           3.9G   30M  3.8G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1       1.4T   36G  1.3T   3% /home
/dev/sdc1       511M   22M  490M   5% /boot/efi
/dev/sda2       1.4T   70M  1.4T   1% /scratch
cgmfs           100K     0  100K   0% /run/cgmanager/fs
tmpfs           785M   60K  784M   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sdd1       7.6G  1.1G  6.6G  15% /media/david/8615-2D9A
/dev/sr0        703M  703M     0 100% /media/david/UDF Volume
```

Output of `sudo fdisk -l`:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 596.2 GiB, 640135028736 bytes, 1250263728 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 37AA04C9-275A-43E5-BFE2-4355CFC935DC

Device     Start        End    Sectors   Size Type    
/dev/sdb1   2048 1250263039 1250260992 596.2G Microsoft basic data

Disk /dev/sda: 2.7 TiB, 3000592982016 bytes, 5860533168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 0CCD5B1E-CFED-4DEC-8416-B44E0CDFCFEA

Device          Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1        2048 2867201266 2867199219  1.3T Linux filesystem
/dev/sda2  2867202048 5860532223 2993330176  1.4T Linux filesystem

Disk /dev/sdc: 55.9 GiB, 60022480896 bytes, 117231408 sectors


Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 41756814-F17E-4683-923A-2459F60FB188

Device         Start       End  Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdc1       2048   1050623  1048576  512M EFI System
/dev/sdc2    1050624 100749311 99698688 47.6G Linux filesystem
/dev/sdc3  100749312 117229567 16480256  7.9G Linux swap

Disk /dev/sdd: 7.6 GiB, 8166703104 bytes, 15950592 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xc3e0984f

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdd1  *    11640 15950591 15938952  7.6G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you give the output of `df -h` ?

I think it is possible if you have enough space available in the big disk to copy all the ubuntu filesystem using `dd` to it. Then you will have to manually modify the grub.

Thanks it seems to me that you have your `/home` in the big disk, and 
the root `/` in the small one.

the output of `sudo fdisk -l` will be helpful to clarify.

Possibly 3 physical disks in `sdb`(all windows) `sda`(home and scratch) and `sdc`(EFI and linux fs).

To be sure please do `lsblk -io KNAME,TYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT`

you can use the partition `sda2` scratch to host your windows.

Comment: Done, check question.

Comment: edit. From the linux side you have many possibilities.